# Parse HTTP/2.0 requests/responses with Go?

Tags: http, go, http2

`/net/http` provides a parser for `HTTP/1.1` in form of [ReadResponse](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ReadResponse) and [ReadRequest](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ReadRequest) functions, but the documentation deliberately says:

> ReadRequest only supports HTTP/1.x requests. For HTTP/2, use golang.org/x/net/http2.

When we go to https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/http2, there is no mention of functions with such capabilities, as far as I can see.

Is there an `HTTP/2.0` parser for go?

Comment: The `Framer` would be the closest thing, I'd say. It doesn't have methods to read/write a full request/response because HTTP2 doesn't work that way.